# How to use checkboxes for creating an array-list of related objects in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a given array of objects, whose objects I would like to add to a 'selected'-list depending on  related checkboxes. How could I set them up without having to set up the controller to much.

Here is the fiddle which works fine, when using radio-boxes instead: 
http://jsfiddle.net/JohannesJo/6ru2R/

**JavaScript:**

```
app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('controller', function($scope){
$scope.aData = [
    {i:1},
    {i:2}
];
$scope.aSelected = [];
});
```

**html:**

```
<body ng-app="app">
        <div ng-controller='controller'>
            <input type = "checkbox" ng-model = "aSelected"  value = "{{aData[0]}}">
            <input type = "checkbox" ng-model = "aSelected"  value = "{{aData[1]}}">

            <div>test:     {{oSelected}}</div>
         </div>
</body>
```

Comment: really not clear what you want. demo uses checkboxes already, not radios. Explain behavior in more detail

Comment: Sorry my fiddles got messed up. I updated the link and the code. Basically i would like to have an array containing the values of the checked checkboxes if they share the same model or - as it is not possible this - some similar functionality.

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/zea7g/6/

Comment: @charilietfl: That is definitely the closest i got so far! Its a little tricky in my special case, but I'll try it. Thank you! I'll wait for another one or two days, but if you post this as answer and no better solution is in sight, I'll give you the credits for the answer!

Comment: @charilietfl: May I also ask, what would be the most angular way to iterate over such an array of objects? Would you use ng-show inside a ng-repeat? Or is there a better and more efficient way?

Comment: iterate in what way? `special case`? not sure what that is..   more details you provide the better

Comment: The "special case" was not an issue (was something with my model, but its not important for the question, as it seems). I mean when I want to show just the the values of the model which have checked=true set in a list. I would either use ng-show or iterate through the array before in the controller. What would you do?

Comment: `ng-show` is for display of an element, define your exact needs. Can iterate over the object but not really sure what you need to do with results

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25394/discussion-between-hugo-der-hungrige-and-charlietfl)

Answer (score 2):

One option is to watch for changes on the `oSelected` Array and create the list of related objects base on it.

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
    return $scope.oSelected;
}, function (value) {
    $scope.selectedItems = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.oSelected, function (v, k) {
        v && $scope.selectedItems.push($scope.aData[k]);
    });
}, true);
```

**jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/zea7g/2/

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking into it atm. The problem is, that i will have to add data binding for the initialization in addition to the code. I was really hoping that there is a way to make checkboxes behaving as smart as radio-boxes. I would argue that it ain't the most counterintuitive thing to want a group of checkboxes to behave like a list of things and not like a 1-0 operator.